# How to allow duplicates in ng-repeat?

Tags: html, json, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using stringify and json is getting formatted and in alert it is coming.But in actual link it is not displaying. When I checked in console error was coming as "duplicates are not allowed in ng-repeat for the key".

Can anyone tell how to allow duplicates in ng-repeat so that formatted json will be printed.

Comment: It would be great to include what you have already tried.

Answer (score 7):

Add 'track by $index' to the repeater.

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes